# R language, problems with SpatialPixelsDataFrame

Tags: r, rgdal

(This question comes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698369/r-language-problems-with-spatialpixelsdataframe?noredirect=1#comment68629240_40698369)

The following two scripts will generate a "SpatialPixelDataFrame" object:

```
# FIRST
library(rgdal)
elev.grid <- readGDAL("whatever.asc")
elev.grid <- as(elev.grid, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")

# SECOND
library(raster)
library(SDMTools)
library(adehabitat)
elev.grid <- raster("whatever.asc")
elev.grid.asc <- asc.from.raster(elev.grid) 
elev.grid.SPDF <- asc2spixdf(elev.grid.asc)
```

However, the first one exceeds the capability of my computing resources when applying it to big (15000 x 16000) grids, and the second one generates an object which I can't use for some of my further analyses. For example, when I use it for krige purposes

```
x <- krige(V3~var, points, elev.grid)
```

I get the following:

> Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula), as(data, "data.frame"), na.action = na.fail) : invalid type (closure) for variable 'var'

Whether providing me a trick to bypass the memory/capability issue in the first case (preferably), or fixing the error generated by the second case please recommend.

Comment: How big is `.asc` file? Are you working in 32-bit or 64-bit version? From R Memory Limit: `The address-space limit is system-specific: 32-bit OSes imposes a limit of no more than 4Gb: it is often 3Gb. Running 32-bit executables on a 64-bit OS will have similar limits: 64-bit executables will have an essentially infinite system-specific limit (e.g., 128Tb for Linux on x86_64 cpus).`

Comment: Gracias @aldo_tapia, I'm running on 64-bit operating system base: Rocks 6.1.1 (Sand Boa), with 128 GB of memory. The .asc is 1550 Mb...

Comment: First workflow seems to me; (1) Build SpatialGridDataFrame by {rgdal}, then (2) Convert SGDF to SPDF directly by raster:: **as()** . (It is not clear if {raster} is called, though). Is it possible to do (1) Build SGDF by {rgdal}, then (2) Convert SGDF to *raster object* by raster:: **raster()** , then (3) Coerce raster object by **as()** ? (I have not tested it myself, sorry. Just thought *raster object* would be generally more efficient in storing big data, and having intermediate object may reduce burden on your machine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different way to obtain a spatial object useful for `gstat`package (`krige()` for Krigging) avoiding `as(object,"Class")` function, is convert it to SpatialPointsDataFrame and grid data.

Try this:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("whatever.asc")
xy <- data.frame(xyFromCell(r, 1:ncell(r)))
v <- getValues(r)
xy[,"z"] <- v
coordinates(xy) <- ~x+y
gridded(xy) <- TRUE
```